# Storing API keys on server

Tags: api, security

I have a service where users each have an API key. I need to store the keys so that they can be used to validate API requests.

If I store the keys in plaintext in my database, I'm worried about the scenario of someone getting access to the db, grabbing all the plaintext api keys, then using them to impersonate others (there will likely be bigger problems if someone got access to the db, though).

This is similar to storing user passwords, where you just store the hash and validate using that - however most APIs let you view your API keys, which means they need to be stored in some recoverable way.

Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: Some servers allow you to view a generated API key exactly *once*, and if you lose it, you must generate a new one. I guess those servers store just the hash of the key?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The threat that someone gets the database and gets the keys means they can use the api keys to access the data in the database, which they already have, so no win there.

The threat that someone can access the database, get the passwords, means they can reuse those passwords on other web sites with the same user name because people tend to reuse their passwords.

Another reason having passwords in the clear or easily reversable is someone in your company could get a hold of the passwords, and start to do bad stuff acting as the user. Which IS a risk you might have if your API keys are in the clear.

Typically, HMAC is a solution for cryptographically computing a secure value from a single secret key, and some public value.

Have a look at HMAC. With HMAC, you can load a secret key into memory with the app (config file, read off of amazon KMS, typed in on app start, or however you want to get that secret key there).

In the database, store a token. `Token = UUID()` for example. The token should be unique to the user, the token could be versioned in case you need to regenerate, and the token could be random (like UUID). The token is not secret.

The API key is computed using the secret key (`SK`) and user token (`UT`) as follows:

```
API_SECRET = HMAC(SK, UT)
```

Then distribute that `UT` (More commonly called API_KEY) and `API_SECRET` to the user, and when the user tries to connect, you compute the `API_SECRET`:

1. Get user record from database (you're probably already asking the user to provide their username)
2. Compute the API_SECRET from the UT in the database:

   ```
   API_SECRET_DB = HMAC(SK, UT)
   ```
3. Compare the computed `API_SECRET_DB` to the one provided in the request:

   if (API_SECRET_DB == API_SECRET_FROM_REQUEST){
   //login user
   }

Bottom line, you only protect the Secret Key, and not every single credential.

Comment: Why not just use the server secret key to encrypt each API key? When the API key comes in over a request, encrypt it, and compare it to the stored, encrypted value. Decrypt the stored value if the API key needs to be displayed.

Comment: HAMC is a one-way encryption commonly used in these types of scenarios. Consider it a type of encryption except that it's one way so you cannot decrypt the data.

Comment: The OP asked about viewing API keys. For one-way hashing where you do not need to recover the original, I would use a password hash  like bcrypt or scrypt for example so that you get key stretching and salting.

Comment: You need bcrypt to salt and stretch a password that is 8 characters. You do not need bcrypt to "stretch" a 256-bit random string (SK). We are talking about API keys and how to prevent them from being viewed in the database. Not passwords that are short and something a person can remember.

Comment: By key stretching, I am referring to stretching the *time* not the bit size. For example, by iterating over a hash 100,000 times.

Comment: You can stretch time best by increasing the bit size / the amount of entropy.

Comment: If I understand this right, this helps (versus just sending a random token) if the database leaks but not the global secret key? I always assumed that if the database leaks, the rest of the prod environment probably is accessible too (and therefore the secret key). Is there a way to avoid the global secret key leaking if the intruder has access to the source code and config files?

Comment: Yes. We typically don’t put secrets in source code or config files that are accessible broadly. The strategy is to only place the secret in a place accessible by the prod machines so that only those with riot access to prod can see them. Example, In aws, this could be KMS and a tight IAM policy limiting to the prod system role account.

Comment: To your other question - there are more common scenarios where the database contents leak and prod is still safe. Here are three cases: 1. database backups are accessed somehow - maybe an S3 bucket with improper permissions. 2. database is copied to a local dev for some troubleshooting. 3. DB logs (ie during a migration) are accidentally shared publicly. and 4. A SQL injection-style attack (sort of like the Equifax breach lets remote people view db contents.)

Comment: Please clarify one confusing point, you wrote "distribute that `API_KEY` and `API_SECRET`".  I'm not clear on what `API_KEY` is.  Should that say `UT` or am I completely missing something obvious?

Comment: Thanks @jonathan just one more question please, what does the user do with their UT?  It appears a user only needs to store & use the `API_SECRET`, which to a user looks and behaves exactly like an API key.

Answer (score -4):

I did an update to some library written in PHP which made it using an **Impersonate Protection Algorithm (IPA)**. that lead to not saving the Token itself inside a database.

[image]

For more info check this https://github.com/vzool/api-hmac-guard

Hope it helps, Thanks